# Запретить перемещение вверх страницы по клику на ссылку jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как запретить перемещение вверх страницы после клика на ссылку?

Сейчас для события клика по ссілке прописано: return false;

Comment: Что значит "запретить перемещение вверх"? Имеется в виду, чтобы после перехода по ссылке, другая страница с таким же значением scrolltop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на событие onclick для ссылки прописано return false, то никаких описанных перемещений  наверх происходить и не будет. В чем вопрос?